# Should I include a paper presented at a conference of which only the abstract was published under publications in my CV?

Tags: publications, conference, paper-submission, cv, abstract

I participated in a conference in which I **submitted** and **presented** a Paper. It didn't get published in their journal, but the *Abstract* and the *Title* of it got published in the **"Book of Abstracts"** which was received by all the attendees of the conference.

Should I write it under publications in my CV ?

If not, how should I mention it in my CV ?

Comment: What field are you in?

Comment: I'm Currently an Engineering Under - Graduate. I'm making an Academic CV to Apply for Higher Education.

Comment: @Buffy Yes, as I mentioned in the Description, I did Present it.

Answer (score 4):

Mention it under "conference presentations".

A printed title and abstract are not enough to convey a paper publication in a CV.